# How can we count 17 particles in the standard model

Tags: terminology, standard-model

This may be a bit of numerology, but I'd like to be able to make a statement like "There are 17 particles in the standard model" with some logical definition of a particle.

But this statement is surprisingly difficult to make in a logically consistent way. The problem is, there are a lot of ways to count particles:

- You can say that every polarization and charge constitutes a distinct particle. This ends up being a huge number of "particles"
- You could classify by multiplets, in which case you'd get get 9 quark fields (ignoring color-charge and anti-particles), whereas I'd want 6.
- You could say something about distinct masses, but both photons and gluons are massless
- You could say something about couplings, but this makes right-handed and left handed fields distinct.

So far the best thing I've come up with is that

- "Particles" are defined as mass eigenstates
- Particles are counted as identical to anything they can be mapped onto with global symmetry transformations (i.e. color charge rotation or charge conjugation).

But I feel like this still leaves room for someone to claim this doesn't lead to a count of 17. Is there any simple rule that leads to this count without simply naming all the particles?

Comment: I think it's more that there are 17 known particles which constitue the standard model - rather than the standard model predicts/requires exactly 17particles.

Comment: maybe my question is unclear, but I'm not asking _why_ we have the particles that we have, just for a way to actually count 17 particles in the known fields. We know that there are anti-particles for each fermion, but I don't want to say there are 24 fermions.

Comment: Why do you think there are specifically $17$?  I think the normal count is six quarks in three colors (18), their antiquarks (18), six leptons, six antileptons, eight gluons, photon, W$^\pm$, Z, Higgs for a total of $60$

Comment: @RossMillikan, I don't think there are specifically 17; the number depends heavily on the definition as you say. What I'm looking for is a concise _definition_. Sort of like Jeopardy, but only sort of...

Comment: https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://www.quantumdiaries.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/2000px-Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg_.jpg&imgrefurl=https://www.quantumdiaries.org/2014/03/14/the-standard-model-a-beautiful-but-flawed-theory/&h=1501&w=2000&tbnid=vNH9Jxi2Ts8WjM:&q=standard+model&tbnh=150&tbnw=200&usg=AI4_-kR3XSp-HwLsdKkw8on_T34DzSkANA&vet=12ahUKEwjtjpW7l9_eAhXbbisKHXbaBNUQ_B0wHnoECAMQBg..i&docid=wvMkC4Euk271uM&itg=1&client=safari&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjtjpW7l9_eAhXbbisKHXbaBNUQ_B0wHnoECAMQBg

Comment: @Virgo the question wasn't so much can you draw a SM representation with 17 particles (you can, of course) but how you would describe the definition of a "particle" that goes into that plot.